# How do I make the width of my sub-menu links the same as its parent?

Tags: html, css

I am very new to programming and am working on a website as a project for a class. I am attempting to create a drop down menu, but I continually run into an issue where my links in the drop down sub-menu are not taking up the full width I would like. See the pic below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6koe.png

I would like the link and thus the hovered white background to extend the full width of the sub-menu but I cannot figure out how to make it work.

Here is my HTML:

```
<header id="mainheader">
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="creativity.html">Creativity</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="skiing.html">Skiing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="island.html">Island</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cooking.html">Cooking</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="revisions.html">Revisions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    

    </header>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}


#mainheader {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #818181;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

#menu li ul.submenu {
  height: auto;
  width: 133px;
  background: #818181;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#menu li:hover ul.submenu {
    display: block;
}

#menu li ul.submenu li {
    width: 133px;
  }

#menu li ul.submenu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` and `width: 100%;` to your `#menu li ul.submenu li a` css rule.

```css
body {
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}


#mainheader {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #818181;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

#menu li ul.submenu {
  height: auto;
  width: 133px;
  background: #818181;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#menu li:hover ul.submenu {
    display: block;
}

#menu li ul.submenu li {
    width: 133px;
  }

#menu li ul.submenu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header id="mainheader">
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="creativity.html">Creativity</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="skiing.html">Skiing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="island.html">Island</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cooking.html">Cooking</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="revisions.html">Revisions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    

    </header>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This worked to get the width correct. However the submenu was inheriting the padding of 10px top and bottom from #menu li, so a quick addition of padding: 0; to #menu li ul.submenu li made everything look just right.